# Проблема в VScode, при начале работы с проектом npx и тд, терминал тормазит и зависает

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, powershell

```
{
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Abyss",
    "terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": false,
    "terminal.integrated.automationProfile.linux": 


}

settings.json
```

Так же установлен GitBash.

Причем ошибки не сыпятся, уже весь инет облазил, но ответа нет.